# duplicate cache in golang

Tags: go, lru

Trying to solve a simple duplicate check using an l1 cache using either of these 2 libraries https://github.com/patrickmn/go-cache or https://github.com/karlseguin/ccache

Several goroutines are executed which fetch a large amount of data from an upstream API.  Inside of each, there is a `for range` loop which checks if the key is a hit or a miss.  In case of a hit, the loop should skip and continue onto the next iteration.   As you may have guessed, the cache should be concurrency safe.   I also instantiate only 1 instance of this cache (`x.cacheInstance`).

```
for _, record := range data {
   ...
   exists := x.cacheInstance.Get(record.DocumentID)
        if exists == nil {
            x.cacheInstance.Set(record.DocumentID, true, time.Minute * 10)
        } else {
            c.logger.Warnw("DocumentID duplicate located", "documentID", record.DocumentID)
            continue
        }
   ...
}
```

However, the application seems to hang, and not continue iterating over records.  Commenting the lru cache check fixes the problem, allowing the program to run as expected.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough code shown to diagnose a program hang. We'd need to see the elided code from this block plus at least the definitions of `cacheInstance`'s type, as well as `cacheInstance.Get` and `cacheInstance.Set`. Try to boil your code down to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace to see where your goroutines are blocking?